# how to pass checkbox array to php from FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox, form-data

Checkbox array can not pass to php through ajax in case of FormData. Following script is working fine where FormData hasn't been used. So I assume problem is in while appending in FormData or passing from it. It returns `invalid arguments supplied for foreach()`.

**Checkbox is not part of form element, so**

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu[]" value="3">

  <form id="form">
  ...........
  </form>
```

**Jquery and ajax**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var navid = [];
        $("[name='menu[]']:checked").each(function (i) {
        navid[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    if (navid.length === 0){ //tell you if the array is empty
        alert("Please Select atleast one checkbox");
    }
    else {
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append('navid', navid);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
foreach ($_POST["navid"] AS $key => $item){               
    $query1 =$con->prepare("INSERT INTO menu(cid, title, en_title) VALUES (:navid, :menuin, :menueng)");
    $query1->bindParam(':menunin',$_POST["menunin"][$key]);
    $query1->bindParam(':menueng',$_POST["menueng"][$key]);
    $query1->bindParam(':navid',$item);
    $query1->execute();
    echo 'Menu has inserted';     
}
```

Comment: your code is perfect. working fine. see in fiddle https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/yEYped. See in network tab

Comment: not the issue, but shouldn't you prepare just once instead of having `prepare()` in the loop?

Comment: @BhumiShah, but it returns `invalid arguments supplied for foreach()` from php. Please see php code, is it OK ?

Comment: do a `print_r($_POST['navid']);` seems the array is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes issue in your php code:

You are passing comma seperated values so first explode and use

```
$data = explode("," ,$_POST["navid"]);
foreach ($data AS $key => $item){
    $query1 =$con->prepare("INSERT INTO menu(cid, title, en_title) VALUES (:navid, :menuin, :menueng)");
    $query1->bindParam(':menunin',$_POST["menunin"][$key]);
    $query1->bindParam(':menueng',$_POST["menueng"][$key]);
    $query1->bindParam(':navid',$item);
    $query1->execute();
    echo 'Menu has inserted';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after exploding, foreach clause is worked but following error is generated `Only variables can be passed by reference` at  `$query1->bindParam(':menunin',$_POST["menunin"][$key])`; I tried a lot, but why this error is coming ?

Comment: Take $_POST["menunin"][$key] and $_POST["menueng"][$key] in variable and pass variable to bindparam value